# I have black screen when i try to switch to a terminal via alt+F1,f2 etc

Tags: command-line, graphics, virtual-console

I have black screen when I try to switch to a terminal via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> etc. I can't see anything!

This happens in many Ubuntu derivatives. I can login blind and enter a command but I can't see anything but a black screen.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us your graphics card and what driver you are using for it. I had a similar problem and fixed it by installing the proprietary drivers for my card.